# Sum of function values in R

Tags: r, function, sum

I am trying to calculate the following ( the image says f(n) = n \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (c(i)*(1-c(i))^n)):

[image]

where c(i) is

```
c <- function(i){1/i^3}
```

In other words, f(2) is 2*{1^(-3)*(1-1^(-3))^2+2^(-3)*(1-2^(-3))^2+3^(-3)*(1-3^(-3))^2+4^(-3)*(1-4^(-3))^2+...}.

How to write such an f function in R?

My initial attempt is:

```
f <- function(n){n*sum(c*(1-c)^n)}
```

but this is obviously wrong with error

```
Error in 1 - c : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Please let me know if further clarification is needed. Thanks.

Comment: what is the `i` going into the function. Also, `c` is a `base R` function

Comment: I can't see the image because my workplace blocks it. But the expression "1 - c" is equivalent to the expression "1 - function(i){1/i^3}", which is obviously not valid

Comment: @akrun i has values from 1 to infinite into the function. Are you able to see the image? Sorry I did not know c was a base function.

Comment: @BillO'Brien https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfvHh.png.  if you can't see the link either, the image says f(n) = n sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (c(i)*(1-c(i))^n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, you can't get an infinite sum unless you tackle it analytically, but since we can see that it's a convergent sum, we could look at, say, the first million like this:

```r
f <- function(n) { 
  C <- 1 / seq(1e6)^3
  n * sum(C * (1 - C)^n)
}
```

Which allows:

```
f(1)
#> [1] 0.1847138
f(2)
#> [1] 0.3387583
f(3)
#> [1] 0.4674204
```

In case you are worried that this is not accurate enough, we get the same result out to 7 digits by summing only the first 10,000 terms, so 1 million should be very close to the converged value.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! Unfortunately, I would prefer not to use first million to approximate it (if possible) for several reasons. I used a toy example in this question, and my actual function f and c are much more complicated. Using first few thousands or million of the values for approximation result in quite a bit of rounding errors and computation time in my situation. Thanks again.

Comment: @J.Z. so you want R to sum infinite terms? That would require an analytic or symbolic solution. Perhaps you should try Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica? Or ask on the naths stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! Your answer is definitely helpful. I am not sure if R can magically somehow handle the infinite sum, and that's why I asked. In my actual functions, because some of my function values are so small that I even had to use Rmpfr() for the desired accuracy. From what you have answered, I think I know my wish is impractical in R. Analytic solution for my actual functions are impossible. Function here in the question is for demonstration purpose. Thanks!

Comment: You can do symbolic calculations in R, using one of the following possibilities: `caracas`, `ryacas`, `rim`. Moreover, via `reticulate` package, you can use the python `sympy` in R.